# Hals-Nasen-Ohren-Arzt (HNO-Arzt) vs. Hals-Nase-Ohren-Arzt oder Hälse-Nasen-Ohren Arzt

Tags: colloquial, abbreviation

Der Hals-Nasen-Ohren-Arzt (HNO-Arzt) beschreibt drei Körperteile.

- Der Hals (Singular da wir nur einen Hals haben)
- Die Ohren (Plural da wir zwei Ohren haben)
- Die Nasen (**Warum Plural?**)

Wir verwenden aus Gewohnheit die Singular-Plural-Plural Kombination. Korrekter wäre doch die Kombination Singular-Singular-Plural (Hals-Nase-Ohren-Arzt) oder die Kombination Plural-Plural-Plural (Hälse-Nasen-Ohren-Arzt).

Warum bilden wir von Nase den Plural?

[Vergleich siehe wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hals-Nasen-Ohren-Heilkunde)

Comment: Eine Möglichkeit: Sprache geht nach Gewohnheit oder Mehrheitsnutzung, nicht nach Gesetzen.

Comment: Kurze Antwort: Es handelt sich hier nicht um den Plural *Nasen*, sondern um den Fugenlaut *n*, der an *Nase* angehängt wird.

Comment: @Björก้้้้้้้้้้้้้้Friedrich: Das sollte eine Antwort sein.

Comment: Geht ein Zyklop zum Augearzt ...

Comment: @Olafant Und die Hydra geht dann zum Hälse-Nasen-Ohren-Arzt ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wie dir vermutlich jeder *Zahnarzt* bestätigen wird, spielt die Logik an dieser Stelle keine große Rolle: *Nasen* ist hier kein Plural, sondern das *n* ist ein [Fugenlaut](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut), wie z.B. auch in *Nasenloch*. Fugenlaute stimmen oft mit Flexionsendungen überein, aber das muss (wie in deinem Beispiel) nichts mit deren Semantik zu tun haben.

Comment: +1 Andere Beispiele: Familienname, Straßenkind, Backentasche, Markenpullover.

Comment: Ist auch "Fugenlaut" ein Beispiel? Oder ist hier wirklich der Plural von "Fuge" gemeint?

Comment: @PaulFrost Ja, das ist auch ein Beispiel, würde ich sagen. Es geht ja nur um eine Fuge (pro Laut).

Comment: Dann passt ja das Wort "Fugenlaut" besonders gut als Bezeichnung des Phänomens "Fugenlaut" ;-)